# How to get the answers in String Array (ie) Vector?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

This is my code:

```
blanks=new EditText(this);
String values =blanks.getText().toString();
answers.put(relative.getId(),answer);
if(answer[0].equals(values)) {
     Toast.makeText(this,"Match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: what do you want and what is the problem you are facing? please explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. You crate a new EditText field, and then immediately get the text. But this will always be null.